# How to echo the current aws configure configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am looking at this article:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/get.html

I just want to echo the current aws cli configuration. Running `aws configure` will prompt for new info, I just want to echo the default info.

The article above says to use `aws configure get`, but that yields:

```
$ aws configure get 
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: too few arguments
```

ultimately, I am just trying to cat the info in `~/.aws/config` file, but I guess I it's possible that aws-cli could be referencing a different file, so want to take that into account. I would also like to be able to echo the info in ~/.aws/credentials, as an aside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `aws configure get` so as to retrieve the value stored in the config file you also need  varname  along with it, such as

```
aws configure get aws_access_key_id

aws configure get aws_secret_access_key
```

Answer (score 1):

`aws configure get` is for getting individual parameters from the config.

There are two possible locations for the files you are after; in `$HOME` or in a location specified by the [ENV vars `AWS_CONFIG_FILE` and `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html).

With parameter expansion, you can use `cat "${AWS_CONFIG_FILE-$HOME}/.aws/config"` and `cat "${AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE-$HOME}/.aws/credentials"` to reliably access things.